# How to upload multiple files (50k+)/ folder to AWS S3 node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, amazon-s3, npm

I've a node js API running on a windows machine which generates some XML files which are later uploaded to S3 bucket. The number of files exceed 50k and sometimes even more.

In my current approach, I'm using [aws-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk) package for uploading. Basically I loop through the folder that needs to be uploaded, read every file and upload it.

```
const files = fs.readdirSync(dirPath, {
            withFileTypes: true
});
for (const file of files) {
      const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(path.join(dirPath, file.name));
      const params = {
          Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
          Key: `${folderPath}/${file.name}`,
          Body: fileContent
      };
      try {
          await s3.upload(params).promise()
      } catch (err) {
          //error handling
          return;
      }
}
```

This takes around 3-4 hours to upload. Is there any better way to bulk upload files? Or if any way to upload entire folder?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/mpuoverview.html

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you zip your folder first, and then upload the zipped folder to the S3. In bash script you can do that as:

```
zip -r data.zip ./target_folder/
```

And then you can upload to S3 as:

```
aws s3 cp ./data.zip s3://bucket_name/
```

Hope that helps!